# Is "should" + 3rd person present correct?

Tags: british-english

My colleague frequently uses "should" + 3rd person present, e.g. "It should goes ..". Notifying him about that he replied he had a British teacher and this form is correct.

It was surprise to me as I thought the correct form is just the verb base form, e.g. "It should go ..". Asking him if it is correct also for negative sentence, e.g. "He should not smokes." he was not sure..

Could someone confirm it is correct and when it is used in this form?

---

**Edit:**

This question has been closed as off-topic. Why?

I was confronted with a person who mentioned a specific usage in a specific country. I googled it first, found [this](https://textranch.com/15743/credit-should-go-to/or/credit-should-goes-to/) - it compares frequency of usages of phrases "credit should go to" vs "credit should goes to" as 17900 : 99. There might be 99 occurrences of a bad usage or there might exist some rare context when it is correct.

Does the question suit better to "English Language Learners"? I wouldn't say from the names of the communities but if the StackExchange thinks so, please feel free to move it there. In my opinion, downvoting and closing without explanation just shows disrespect to the urge to understand things..

Comment: Modals take the **base-form**, not a tensed form: '**go**' / '**smoke**'. I can't imagine any Brit (or any native speaker), let alone a teacher,  teaching 'It should goes ...' as correct.

Comment: It's **never** correct to use the third person singular present tense verb form (the one that ends in -S -- _is, goes, says, wants, has, likes, ..._) after any auxiliary verb, including modal auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @JohnLawler +1 Indeed and after any verb at all, in fact!

Comment: The question is closed because under no circumstances would "should"  accompany the tensed form of a verb. As a modal, it only takes the bare infinitive. You have an 'answer in comment' from [John Lawler](https://lsa.umich.edu/linguistics/people/faculty/professors-emeriti/jlawler.html) ...that *should is sufficient. /// Also, we can no longer migrate the question unless you make a direct appeal to a diamond Mod.

Comment: To any diamond mod - I'm absolutely fine with migrating this question to a better fit community, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, if there is an auxiliary verb like "**should**" in the sentence, the verb that comes directly after it needs to be in its "**base form**", i.e.:

- "It should **go**.."
- "He can **run**.."
- "She will **win**.."

You can find more about this topic [here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-should.htm) and [here](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/auxiliary_verbs.htm#:%7E:text=%20Examples%20of%20Modal%20Auxiliary%20Verbs%20%201,go%20on.%20%28American%20Poet%20Carl%20Sandburg%29%20More%20).

Comment: I suspect that you are being down-voted (not mine) because you have presented an overly simplistic answer to a question which was already too trivial for this site...